# Usng R - gsub using code in replacement - Replace comma with full stop after pattern

Tags: r, string, replace, text-mining, gsub

I would like to manually correct a record by using R. Last name and first name should always be separated by a comma.

```
names <- c("ADAM, Smith J.", "JOHNSON. Richard", "BROWN, Wilhelm K.", "DAVIS, Daniel")
```

Sometimes, however, a full stop has crept in as a separator, as in the case of "JOHNSON. Richard". I would like to do this automatically. Since the last name is always at the beginning of the line, I can simply access it via `sub`:

```
sub("^[[:upper:]]+\\.","^[[:upper:]]+\\,",names)
```

However, I cannot use a function for the replacement that specifically replaces the full stop with a comma.

Is there a way to insert a function into the replacement that does this for me?

Comment: You'd just like to put your code into a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `sub` is mostly correct, but you'll need a capture group (the brackets and backreference `\\1`) for the replacement.

Because we are "capturing" the upper case letters, therefore `\\1` here represents the original upper case letters in your original strings. The only replacement here is `\\.` to `\\,`. In other words, we are replacing upper case letters `^(([[:upper:]]+)` **AND** full stop `\\.` with it's original content `\\1` **AND** comma `\\,`.

For more details you can visit this [page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html).

```
test_names <- c("ADAM, Smith J.", "JOHNSON. Richard", "BROWN, Wilhelm K.", "DAVIS, Daniel")

sub("^([[:upper:]]+)\\.","\\1\\,",test_names)
[1] "ADAM, Smith J."    "JOHNSON, Richard"  "BROWN, Wilhelm K."
[4] "DAVIS, Daniel"
```

Comment: Thank you, that solves my problem. I wasn't aware that I could position the replacement after `\\1`.

Comment: Done, can I may aske a question regarding to your sollution. Why konws `"\\1\\,"` that it should replace the **.** by **,** and not the **upper** letter by **,**?

Comment: Because we are "capturing" the upper case letters, therefore `\\1` here represents the original upper case letters in your original strings. The only replacement here is `\\.` to `\\,`. In other words, we are replacing upper case letters `^(([[:upper:]]+)` AND full stop `\\.` with it's original content `\\1` AND comma `\\,`

Comment: For more details, you can take a look at this [page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) :)

Answer (score 1):

Can be done by a function like so:

```
names <- c("ADAM, Smith", "JOHNSON. Richard", "BROWN, Wilhelm", "DAVIS, Daniel")

replacedots <- function(mystring) {
  gsub("\\.", ",", names)
}
replacedots(names)
[1] "ADAM, Smith"      "JOHNSON, Richard" "BROWN, Wilhelm"   "DAVIS, Daniel"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I noticed that I forgot an important point in my question. The text strings are longer than shown and also contain abbreviated middle names. If I were to automatically replace each point with a comma, I would cause more errors than I would fix. I therefore thought to use capitalisation to correct. However, I cannot specify a function in the replacement

Comment: Could you please explain why you'd like to use a function in the replacement? What would be your expected function doing?

Comment: This is the strucutur of gsub: `gsub(pattern, replacement, x)`

**pattern:** Here I want to identify all cases that are at the beginning of a string with `^` and followed by uppercase letters with `[[:upper:]]+` and then a dot `\.`

**replace:** Here I want to replace `\.` with `\,` in previously identified string.  I tried to insert this `"^[[:upper:]]+\,"` in replacement (I don't know what the technical term for this is, function is probably wrong), however it then gives me `"^[[:upper:]]+, Richard"`  instead of "JOHNSON, Richard" .